# zsh and dynamic variable

Tags: shell, zsh

I have a TARGET variable that can be set to dev, test or prod.

I defined the following lists:

```
dev=(server1 user1 target1)
test=(server2 user2 target2)
prod=(server3 user3 target3)
```

Depending on the value of TARGET, I'd like to dynamically associate the variable CONFIG to one of the list.

Let's say TARGET=dev. I then have

```
eval CONFIG=\$$TARGET # I expect CONFIG to be a list containing (server1 user1 target1)
echo ${CONFIG[*]}     # OK, it gives (server1 user1 target1)
echo ${CONFIG[1]}    # I would expect to have "server1" but it returns "1", seems like CONFIG is not seen as a list
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`eval CONFIG=\$$TARGET` sets `CONFIG` to the string `$TARGET`. When an array is expanded in a string context, the result is the concatenation of the values in the array, with the first character of `IFS` inserted as a separator. Thus after the assignment the value of `CONFIG` is the string `server1 user1 target1`.

You need to assign to `CONFIG` as an array. Since you're working in zsh, you don't need to use `eval` to obtain the value of a variable whose name is in a variable. Use the `P` [parameter expansion flag](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags).

```
CONFIG=(${(P)TARGET})
```